# php and mysql foreach only displays the first record four times

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, while-loop

I built a function to get the records from the database, and I'm trying to print the results using a foreach loop.

Here's my function:

```
function get_posts($connection) {

    $posts = array();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY stamp DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

    while ($post = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
        $posts = array('body'        => $post->body,
                       'stamp'      => $post->stamp,
                       'post_id'    => $post->id,
                       'user_id'    => $post->user_id);

    }
        return $posts;
}
```

And now I'm trying to display the results using the following code:

```
  $posts = get_posts($connection);
  foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
    echo $posts['body'] . "<hr>";
  }
```

When using that bit of code it only returns the first record from the database 4 times. I've used var_dump to make sure it's indeed an array, and it is. I must be using the foreach loop incorrectly here.

PS: Could the **mysqli_fetch_object** be turned into **mysqli_fetch_assoc** for that matter? I think it might be easier to use that but I don't know how to use it inside a function. Any code bits are appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should `put` new elements into new indexes of array like this:

```
while ($post = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
    $posts[] = array('body'        => $post->body,
                   'stamp'      => $post->stamp,
                   'post_id'    => $post->id,
                   'user_id'    => $post->user_id);

}
```

Note that before this you should initialize $post as an array like:

```
$posts = array();
```

and then you can retrieve information this way:

```
foreach($posts as $postInfo) {
    foreach($postInfo as $key => $val) {
        echo '<p>' .$key . ':&nbsp;' . $val. '</p>';
   }
}
```

this will echo :

`body` : `foo`
`stamp` : `(timestamp)` 
... 
...

Comment: That seems to work. Could you please explain why you're using two foreach loops to get the results? You first get the $posts and then setting it as $postinfo, then using that $postinfo. Couldn't you just use $posts as $key => $val ?

Comment: because here `$posts` is a multidimensional array each index in this array contains another array which holds a pair of keys and values.

Comment: according to `rasmus lerdorf` never use `array_push` function because it has performance issues instead use the actual syntax for pushing new elements into array: `$arr[] = 'lastOne'`;

Comment: I see, Well, thanks a lot for taking time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `get_posts` you override the previous values in the `$posts` array.
Try this:

```
array_push($posts, array('body' => $post->body,
                   'stamp'   => $post->stamp,
                   'post_id' => $post->id,
                   'user_id' => $post->user_id));
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/includes/functions.php on line 11

Comment: It works for me. I have to see all your fixed relevant code to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `$posts` into a multidimensional array which can easily be done by doing this:

```
...
$posts[] = array('body'        => $post->body,
...
```

then the rest of your code will work as you planned.

Comment: Now it throws the following error :  Notice: Undefined index: body in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/blog/index.php on line 26 - Line 26 being the echo $postts['body']; line

Comment: according to your comment you have posts misspelled as postts